# Use the Imagemagick tile index for output filenames

Tags: imagemagick

I'm running the following, which is nearly correct:

```
convert joint/* \
    -limit memory 512MiB \
    -crop 2x1@ +repage +adjoin \
    -set filename:fn '%t-%[fx:p&1].%e' \
    'separate/%[filename:fn]'
```

It splits each image in a directory of images into two images each. `fx` is used to alternate tile indices between 0 and 1. However, some image halves in the output directory are mysteriously missing:

```
0_stereoscopic_views_-_kilburn_-_royal_botanic_gardens-0.jpg
0_stereoscopic_views_-_kilburn_-_royal_botanic_gardens-1.jpg
1080par-0.jpg
1240637960_ec87a611d8_b-0.jpg
1244683205_6e516f7070_b-0.jpg
1291632940_184b45e999_b-0.jpg
1291633886_e6d486735c_b-0.jpg
1339211763_9a2b2c4c26_b-0.jpg
1343608989_a270398ca8_b-0.jpg
1344499170_e6f028b93f_b-0.jpg
1732812547_2034be2b6d_b-0.jpg
1732812547_2034be2b6d_b-1.jpg
3d_stereoscopic_experiment_by_hungerartist-0.jpg
3d_stereoscopic_experiment_by_hungerartist-1.jpg
3D_stereoscopic_projection_truncated_tesseract-0.PNG
594937060_e9e3ae842f_o-0.jpg
666646137_af04950174_b-0.jpg
666646137_af04950174_b-1.jpg
666646251_16c24f77fd_b-0.jpg
666646251_16c24f77fd_b-1.jpg
701546256_473abfaf62_b-0.jpg
701546256_473abfaf62_b-1.jpg
712859467_bcc1701192_b-0.jpg
712859467_bcc1701192_b-1.jpg
740097278_727827502f_b-0.jpg
967929784_38cc70efc8_b-0.jpg
Bee in Flight-0.jpg
Burning Man 2009 - Torch Spinner-0.jpg
Burning Man 2010 - Lobster Taxi-0.jpg
Burning Man 2011 - Temple of Transition-0.jpg
Burning Man 2011 - Temple of Transition-1.jpg
ChaitanyaKrishnanFINAL-0.JPG
Dinosaur-0.jpg
Dinosaur 2-0.jpg
Early_bird_stereograph2-1.jpg
Exo-Frame-1.jpg
Fall 3D-0.jpg
Fall 3D 2-1.jpg
Fireworks-0.jpg
gm-stereoscopic-test2-1.jpg
gm-stereoscopic-test3-0.jpg
gm-stereoscopic-test4-0.jpg
JasdeepSinghFINAL-0.JPG
Kids around the World-0.jpg
Klingenthal-1.jpg
Las Vegas January 2010-0.jpg
Munich, Maximilian Avenue-1.jpg
Peering through the Petals-0.jpg
Peering through the Petals-1.jpg
Piano_in_3D-0.jpg
Reflections-0.jpg
splat-0.jpg
spooky-0.jpg
Stereoscopic_Gibberlings_by_slipgatecentral-0.jpg
Theatre of Food-0.jpg
TimBorisovFINAL-1.JPG
Water balloon-0.jpg
Wernigerode Westerntor-1.jpg
WK2007_1_Melancolia-0.jpg
WK2007_1_Melancolia-1.jpg
WK2007_4_Larder-0.jpg
WK2007_4_Larder-1.jpg
```

Why would this be?

Edit: It appears that there is some sketchiness going on regarding `%p`. Sometimes it updates, and sometimes it doesn't, leading to this output on verbose:

```
joint/0_stereoscopic_views_-_kilburn_-_royal_botanic_gardens.jpg=>separate/0_stereoscopic_views_-_kilburn_-_royal_botanic_gardens-2.jpg[0] JPEG 640x324=>320x324 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 20.5KB 42.370u 0:29.949
joint/0_stereoscopic_views_-_kilburn_-_royal_botanic_gardens.jpg=>separate/0_stereoscopic_views_-_kilburn_-_royal_botanic_gardens-1.jpg[1] JPEG 640x324=>320x324 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 20.5KB 42.360u 0:29.969
joint/1080par.jpg=>separate/1080par-1.jpg[2] JPEG 1238x720=>619x720 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 81.9KB 42.170u 0:29.829
joint/1080par.jpg=>separate/1080par-1.jpg[3] JPEG 1238x720=>619x720 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 81.9KB 42.170u 0:29.830
joint/1240637960_ec87a611d8_b.jpg=>separate/1240637960_ec87a611d8_b-1.jpg[4] JPEG 1024x641=>512x641 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 86KB 41.970u 0:29.729
joint/1240637960_ec87a611d8_b.jpg=>separate/1240637960_ec87a611d8_b-1.jpg[5] JPEG 1024x641=>512x641 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 86KB 41.970u 0:29.730
joint/1244683205_6e516f7070_b.jpg=>separate/1244683205_6e516f7070_b-1.jpg[6] JPEG 1024x643=>512x643 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 102KB 41.770u 0:29.610
joint/1244683205_6e516f7070_b.jpg=>separate/1244683205_6e516f7070_b-1.jpg[7] JPEG 1024x643=>512x643 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 102KB 41.780u 0:29.609
joint/1291632940_184b45e999_b.jpg=>separate/1291632940_184b45e999_b-1.jpg[8] JPEG 1024x640=>512x640 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 123KB 41.540u 0:29.500
joint/1291632940_184b45e999_b.jpg=>separate/1291632940_184b45e999_b-1.jpg[9] JPEG 1024x640=>512x640 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 123KB 41.550u 0:29.500
joint/1291633886_e6d486735c_b.jpg=>separate/1291633886_e6d486735c_b-1.jpg[10] JPEG 1024x641=>512x641 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 123KB 41.320u 0:29.339
joint/1291633886_e6d486735c_b.jpg=>separate/1291633886_e6d486735c_b-1.jpg[11] JPEG 1024x641=>512x641 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 119KB 41.320u 0:29.330
joint/1339211763_9a2b2c4c26_b.jpg=>separate/1339211763_9a2b2c4c26_b-1.jpg[12] JPEG 1024x640=>512x640 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 152KB 41.080u 0:29.230
joint/1339211763_9a2b2c4c26_b.jpg=>separate/1339211763_9a2b2c4c26_b-1.jpg[13] JPEG 1024x640=>512x640 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 152KB 41.080u 0:29.219
joint/1343608989_a270398ca8_b.jpg=>separate/1343608989_a270398ca8_b-1.jpg[14] JPEG 1024x641=>512x641 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 86KB 40.860u 0:29.099
joint/1343608989_a270398ca8_b.jpg=>separate/1343608989_a270398ca8_b-1.jpg[15] JPEG 1024x641=>512x641 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 86KB 40.860u 0:29.109
joint/1344499170_e6f028b93f_b.jpg=>separate/1344499170_e6f028b93f_b-1.jpg[16] JPEG 1024x639=>512x639 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 32.8KB 40.720u 0:29.030
joint/1344499170_e6f028b93f_b.jpg=>separate/1344499170_e6f028b93f_b-1.jpg[17] JPEG 1024x639=>512x639 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 41KB 40.720u 0:29.020
joint/1732812547_2034be2b6d_b.jpg=>separate/1732812547_2034be2b6d_b-1.jpg[18] JPEG 1024x341=>512x341 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 86KB 40.590u 0:28.919
joint/1732812547_2034be2b6d_b.jpg=>separate/1732812547_2034be2b6d_b-2.jpg[19] JPEG 1024x341=>512x341 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 90.1KB 40.590u 0:28.919
joint/3d_stereoscopic_experiment_by_hungerartist.jpg=>separate/3d_stereoscopic_experiment_by_hungerartist-1.jpg[20] JPEG 1584x622=>792x622 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 102KB 40.250u 0:28.740
joint/3d_stereoscopic_experiment_by_hungerartist.jpg=>separate/3d_stereoscopic_experiment_by_hungerartist-2.jpg[21] JPEG 1584x622=>792x622 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 94.2KB 40.250u 0:28.739
joint/3D_stereoscopic_projection_truncated_tesseract.PNG=>separate/3D_stereoscopic_projection_truncated_tesseract-1.jpg[22] PNG 614x304=>307x304 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 20.5KB 40.220u 0:28.730
joint/3D_stereoscopic_projection_truncated_tesseract.PNG=>separate/3D_stereoscopic_projection_truncated_tesseract-1.jpg[23] PNG 614x304=>307x304 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 20.5KB 40.220u 0:28.730
joint/594937060_e9e3ae842f_o.jpg=>separate/594937060_e9e3ae842f_o-1.jpg[24] JPEG 1024x683=>512x683 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 49.2KB 39.980u 0:28.580
joint/594937060_e9e3ae842f_o.jpg=>separate/594937060_e9e3ae842f_o-1.jpg[25] JPEG 1024x683=>512x683 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 53.2KB 39.980u 0:28.579
joint/666646137_af04950174_b.jpg=>separate/666646137_af04950174_b-1.jpg[26] JPEG 1024x630=>512x630 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 156KB 39.760u 0:28.449
joint/666646137_af04950174_b.jpg=>separate/666646137_af04950174_b-2.jpg[27] JPEG 1024x630=>512x630 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 160KB 39.760u 0:28.459
joint/666646251_16c24f77fd_b.jpg=>separate/666646251_16c24f77fd_b-1.jpg[28] JPEG 1024x382=>512x382 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 94.2KB 39.630u 0:28.389
joint/666646251_16c24f77fd_b.jpg=>separate/666646251_16c24f77fd_b-2.jpg[29] JPEG 1024x382=>512x382 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 94.2KB 39.630u 0:28.399
joint/701546256_473abfaf62_b.jpg=>separate/701546256_473abfaf62_b-1.jpg[30] JPEG 1024x631=>512x631 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 119KB 39.500u 0:28.240
joint/701546256_473abfaf62_b.jpg=>separate/701546256_473abfaf62_b-2.jpg[31] JPEG 1024x631=>512x631 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 119KB 39.500u 0:28.239
joint/712859467_bcc1701192_b.jpg=>separate/712859467_bcc1701192_b-1.jpg[32] JPEG 1024x630=>512x630 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 53.2KB 39.410u 0:28.199
joint/712859467_bcc1701192_b.jpg=>separate/712859467_bcc1701192_b-2.jpg[33] JPEG 1024x630=>512x630 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 49.2KB 39.410u 0:28.199
joint/740097278_727827502f_b.jpg=>separate/740097278_727827502f_b-1.jpg[34] JPEG 1024x663=>512x663 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 147KB 39.160u 0:28.009
joint/740097278_727827502f_b.jpg=>separate/740097278_727827502f_b-1.jpg[35] JPEG 1024x663=>512x663 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 156KB 39.170u 0:28.019
joint/967929784_38cc70efc8_b.jpg=>separate/967929784_38cc70efc8_b-1.jpg[36] JPEG 1024x626=>512x626 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 119KB 38.950u 0:27.879
joint/967929784_38cc70efc8_b.jpg=>separate/967929784_38cc70efc8_b-1.jpg[37] JPEG 1024x626=>512x626 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 111KB 38.950u 0:27.890
joint/Bee in Flight.jpg=>separate/Bee in Flight-1.jpg[38] JPEG 1024x579=>512x579 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 86KB 38.780u 0:27.800
joint/Bee in Flight.jpg=>separate/Bee in Flight-1.jpg[39] JPEG 1024x579=>512x579 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 81.9KB 38.790u 0:27.810
joint/Burning Man 2009 - Torch Spinner.jpg=>separate/Burning Man 2009 - Torch Spinner-1.jpg[40] JPEG 1024x609=>512x609 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 102KB 38.560u 0:27.669
joint/Burning Man 2009 - Torch Spinner.jpg=>separate/Burning Man 2009 - Torch Spinner-1.jpg[41] JPEG 1024x609=>512x609 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 98.3KB 38.560u 0:27.660
joint/Burning Man 2010 - Lobster Taxi.jpg=>separate/Burning Man 2010 - Lobster Taxi-1.jpg[42] JPEG 1024x539=>512x539 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 127KB 38.350u 0:27.519
joint/Burning Man 2010 - Lobster Taxi.jpg=>separate/Burning Man 2010 - Lobster Taxi-1.jpg[43] JPEG 1024x539=>512x539 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 131KB 38.350u 0:27.529
joint/Burning Man 2011 - Temple of Transition.jpg=>separate/Burning Man 2011 - Temple of Transition-2.jpg[44] JPEG 1024x426=>512x426 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 86KB 38.190u 0:27.439
joint/Burning Man 2011 - Temple of Transition.jpg=>separate/Burning Man 2011 - Temple of Transition-1.jpg[45] JPEG 1024x426=>512x426 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 81.9KB 38.190u 0:27.440
joint/ChaitanyaKrishnanFINAL.JPG=>separate/ChaitanyaKrishnanFINAL-1.jpg[46] JPEG 3336x1050=>1668x1050 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 197KB 36.930u 0:26.699
joint/ChaitanyaKrishnanFINAL.JPG=>separate/ChaitanyaKrishnanFINAL-1.jpg[47] JPEG 3336x1050=>1668x1050 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 188KB 36.920u 0:26.710
joint/Dinosaur 2.jpg=>separate/Dinosaur 2-1.jpg[48] JPEG 1600x1001=>800x1001 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 193KB 36.380u 0:26.390
joint/Dinosaur 2.jpg=>separate/Dinosaur 2-1.jpg[49] JPEG 1600x1001=>800x1001 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 217KB 36.380u 0:26.410
joint/Dinosaur.jpg=>separate/Dinosaur-1.jpg[50] JPEG 1600x1032=>800x1032 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 147KB 35.860u 0:26.089
joint/Dinosaur.jpg=>separate/Dinosaur-1.jpg[51] JPEG 1600x1032=>800x1032 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 152KB 35.860u 0:26.089
joint/Early_bird_stereograph2.jpg=>separate/Early_bird_stereograph2-2.jpg[52] JPEG 1522x727=>761x727 8-bit Grayscale PseudoClass 256c 250KB 35.850u 0:26.100
joint/Early_bird_stereograph2.jpg=>separate/Early_bird_stereograph2-2.jpg[53] JPEG 1522x727=>761x727 8-bit Grayscale PseudoClass 256c 262KB 35.850u 0:26.099
joint/Exo-Frame.jpg=>separate/Exo-Frame-2.jpg[54] JPEG 1256x1050=>628x1050 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 344KB 35.370u 0:25.820
joint/Exo-Frame.jpg=>separate/Exo-Frame-2.jpg[55] JPEG 1256x1050=>628x1050 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 356KB 35.380u 0:25.829
joint/Fall 3D 2.jpg=>separate/Fall 3D 2-2.jpg[56] JPEG 5894x2224=>2947x2224 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 1.589MB 31.000u 0:23.269
joint/Fall 3D 2.jpg=>separate/Fall 3D 2-2.jpg[57] JPEG 5894x2224=>2947x2224 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 1.634MB 31.040u 0:23.179
joint/Fall 3D.jpg=>separate/Fall 3D-1.jpg[58] JPEG 5304x1997=>2652x1997 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 2.089MB 27.170u 0:19.429
joint/Fall 3D.jpg=>separate/Fall 3D-1.jpg[59] JPEG 5304x1997=>2652x1997 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 2.085MB 27.240u 0:18.890
joint/Fireworks.jpg=>separate/Fireworks-1.jpg[60] JPEG 1280x990=>640x990 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 156KB 26.980u 0:18.579
joint/Fireworks.jpg=>separate/Fireworks-1.jpg[61] JPEG 1280x990=>640x990 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 156KB 26.980u 0:18.550
joint/gm-stereoscopic-test2.jpg=>separate/gm-stereoscopic-test2-2.jpg[62] JPEG 1280x384=>640x384 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 152KB 26.800u 0:18.439
joint/gm-stereoscopic-test2.jpg=>separate/gm-stereoscopic-test2-2.jpg[63] JPEG 1280x384=>640x384 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 156KB 26.800u 0:18.449
joint/gm-stereoscopic-test3.jpg=>separate/gm-stereoscopic-test3-1.jpg[64] JPEG 1440x432=>720x432 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 201KB 26.570u 0:18.300
joint/gm-stereoscopic-test3.jpg=>separate/gm-stereoscopic-test3-1.jpg[65] JPEG 1440x432=>720x432 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 205KB 26.580u 0:18.309
joint/gm-stereoscopic-test4.jpg=>separate/gm-stereoscopic-test4-1.jpg[66] JPEG 1440x432=>720x432 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 201KB 26.350u 0:18.179
joint/gm-stereoscopic-test4.jpg=>separate/gm-stereoscopic-test4-1.jpg[67] JPEG 1440x432=>720x432 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 197KB 26.350u 0:18.189
joint/JasdeepSinghFINAL.JPG=>separate/JasdeepSinghFINAL-1.jpg[68] JPEG 3168x1260=>1584x1260 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 49.2KB 25.710u 0:17.779
joint/JasdeepSinghFINAL.JPG=>separate/JasdeepSinghFINAL-1.jpg[69] JPEG 3168x1260=>1584x1260 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 49.2KB 25.700u 0:17.769
joint/Kids around the World.jpg=>separate/Kids around the World-1.jpg[70] JPEG 7054x2696=>3527x2696 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 1.552MB 18.640u 0:13.640
joint/Kids around the World.jpg=>separate/Kids around the World-1.jpg[71] JPEG 7054x2696=>3527x2696 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 1.749MB 18.680u 0:13.179
joint/Klingenthal.jpg=>separate/Klingenthal-2.jpg[72] JPEG 1560x650=>780x650 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 221KB 18.210u 0:11.660
joint/Klingenthal.jpg=>separate/Klingenthal-2.jpg[73] JPEG 1560x650=>780x650 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 205KB 18.210u 0:11.670
joint/Las Vegas January 2010.jpg=>separate/Las Vegas January 2010-1.jpg[74] JPEG 6870x2575=>3435x2575 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 4.276MB 11.830u 0:08.030
joint/Las Vegas January 2010.jpg=>separate/Las Vegas January 2010-1.jpg[75] JPEG 6870x2575=>3435x2575 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 4.366MB 12.000u 0:08.230
joint/Munich, Maximilian Avenue.jpg=>separate/Munich, Maximilian Avenue-2.jpg[76] JPEG 1500x1080=>750x1080 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 377KB 11.330u 0:07.789
joint/Munich, Maximilian Avenue.jpg=>separate/Munich, Maximilian Avenue-2.jpg[77] JPEG 1500x1080=>750x1080 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 397KB 11.340u 0:07.820
joint/Peering through the Petals.jpg=>separate/Peering through the Petals-2.jpg[78] JPEG 962x500=>481x500 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 94.2KB 11.160u 0:07.710
joint/Peering through the Petals.jpg=>separate/Peering through the Petals-1.jpg[79] JPEG 962x500=>481x500 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 90.1KB 11.170u 0:07.710
joint/Piano_in_3D.jpg=>separate/Piano_in_3D-1.jpg[80] JPEG 720x272=>360x272 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 24.6KB 11.110u 0:07.679
joint/Piano_in_3D.jpg=>separate/Piano_in_3D-1.jpg[81] JPEG 720x272=>360x272 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 24.6KB 11.110u 0:07.690
joint/Reflections.jpg=>separate/Reflections-1.jpg[82] JPEG 2088x1015=>1044x1015 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 442KB 10.400u 0:07.269
joint/Reflections.jpg=>separate/Reflections-1.jpg[83] JPEG 2088x1015=>1044x1015 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 537KB 10.420u 0:07.280
joint/splat.jpg=>separate/splat-1.jpg[84] JPEG 1886x1200=>943x1200 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 41KB 10.160u 0:07.140
joint/splat.jpg=>separate/splat-1.jpg[85] JPEG 1886x1200=>943x1200 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 41KB 10.160u 0:07.160
joint/spooky.jpg=>separate/spooky-1.jpg[86] JPEG 1600x984=>800x984 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 143KB 9.820u 0:06.939
joint/spooky.jpg=>separate/spooky-1.jpg[87] JPEG 1600x984=>800x984 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 147KB 9.830u 0:06.949
joint/Stereoscopic_Gibberlings_by_slipgatecentral.jpg=>separate/Stereoscopic_Gibberlings_by_slipgatecentral-1.jpg[88] JPEG 1000x459=>500x459 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 77.8KB 9.660u 0:06.870
joint/Stereoscopic_Gibberlings_by_slipgatecentral.jpg=>separate/Stereoscopic_Gibberlings_by_slipgatecentral-1.jpg[89] JPEG 1000x459=>500x459 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 81.9KB 9.650u 0:06.860
joint/Theatre of Food.jpg=>separate/Theatre of Food-1.jpg[90] JPEG 7100x1997=>3550x1997 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 3.555MB 4.630u 0:03.919
joint/Theatre of Food.jpg=>separate/Theatre of Food-1.jpg[91] JPEG 7100x1997=>3550x1997 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 3.51MB 4.740u 0:04.089
joint/TimBorisovFINAL.JPG=>separate/TimBorisovFINAL-2.jpg[92] JPEG 3304x1050=>1652x1050 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 143KB 3.710u 0:03.440
joint/TimBorisovFINAL.JPG=>separate/TimBorisovFINAL-2.jpg[93] JPEG 3304x1050=>1652x1050 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 143KB 3.710u 0:03.449
joint/Water balloon.jpg=>separate/Water balloon-1.jpg[94] JPEG 1024x615=>512x615 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 152KB 3.470u 0:03.329
joint/Water balloon.jpg=>separate/Water balloon-1.jpg[95] JPEG 1024x615=>512x615 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 147KB 3.470u 0:03.339
joint/Wernigerode Westerntor.jpg=>separate/Wernigerode Westerntor-2.jpg[96] JPEG 1540x1080=>770x1080 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 328KB 2.980u 0:03.039
joint/Wernigerode Westerntor.jpg=>separate/Wernigerode Westerntor-2.jpg[97] JPEG 1540x1080=>770x1080 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 332KB 2.990u 0:03.050
joint/WK2007_1_Melancolia.jpg=>separate/WK2007_1_Melancolia-1.jpg[98] JPEG 650x323=>325x323 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 45.1KB 2.910u 0:03.000
joint/WK2007_1_Melancolia.jpg=>separate/WK2007_1_Melancolia-2.jpg[99] JPEG 650x323=>325x323 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 45.1KB 2.910u 0:03.000
joint/WK2007_4_Larder.jpg=>separate/WK2007_4_Larder-1.jpg[100] JPEG 650x323=>325x323 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 41KB 2.830u 0:02.970
joint/WK2007_4_Larder.jpg=>separate/WK2007_4_Larder-2.jpg[101] JPEG 650x323=>325x323 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 41KB 2.830u 0:02.970
```

Another edit: read https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/imagemagick/+bug/1079813 and then http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22387 - this is an ImageMagick bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the linked forum post, the only solution is to upgrade to ImageMagick 7.